# Kohana 3 and the "Too many connections" error

Tags: php, mysql, kohana

I have a web application in production that manages an internal system and a web page, both in relation. Not only as a CMS+Web, both works like a user-control-system, requests-management, CMS and web. Both systems have too many users (admins, editors and final-users). The system uses MySQL as DB engine.

So, you are in context now.

I had the following SQL error;

```
Database_Exception [ 0 ]: [1040] Too many connections ~ MODPATH/database/classes/kohana/database/mysql.php [ 67 ]
```

Looking at the server side, it's real, the server had too many connections to the DB Engine. The message is right.

The website was down. I restart Apache and everything works fine.
But obviously this would ever happen.

I'm googling and reading the MySQL manual and see that exists a configuration to increase the connections number (from 151, the default, to another value).
But, I'm reading about the Kohana config and I read that exists a queries caché system (into the database configuration file). So, I don't know if that cache "saves" in memory the query result or it the cache "saves" the query itself to prevent the overload of Query_Builder or ORM, so if the query had been previously generated don't re-generate it and only execute it.

I need a solution but avoiding (as possible as it could be) the MySQL config modification.

Thanks!

Comment: do you use persistent connections? (check kohana db config file)

Comment: no, i don't use persistent connections (it's setted to false)

Answer (score 0):

Check your setting of `max_connections` in the mysql config file `my.ini`. The default setting is 100, you may change it to 300 or more.

Then, look what processes are connected to mysql with the command `netstat -np`, and kill unknown ones.

After all changes restart you mysql daemon:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld restart
```

If this doesn't help, read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html

And do not forget make dumps for all mysql dbs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I writed in mi question: "I need a solution but avoiding (as possible) the MySQL config modification" because the Database Administration is in another Area in the Organization and I want to solve it from my side.